# Deformation of toric varieties to complete intersections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, toric-varieties, complete-intersection

I am looking for some systematic study/examples of families of projective complete intersection varieties degenerating to a projective toric variety. In particular, given a projective toric variety, when can I smoothen/deform it into a complete intersection variety?  What kind of singularities are permitted for such toric varieties? A reference which deals with such questions will be very helpful.

Comment: What is your definition of "complete intersection variety"?  Do you mean a projective scheme whose local rings are each a quotient of a regular local ring by an ideal generated by a regular sequence?  Or do you mean a codimension $c$ intersection of $c$ ample hypersurfaces in a projective space?

Comment: @JasonStarr I mean the latter i.e., codimension c intersection of c ample hypersurfaces in a projective space.